# Refactor code to get HostnameVerifier per instance

Tags: java

I have this Java class which checks if the `instance` is not blank and matches `dev`/`qa`/`stg`/`staging`/`prod` and `hostnameVerification` is `true` then `getHostnameVerifierForInstance` returns a customized `HostnameVerifier`.

```
public class SSLConfig {
    private static final String PROD_INSTANCE = "Prod";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE1 = "Staging";
    private static final String STG_INSTANCE2 = "Stg";
    private static final String QA_INSTANCE = "QA";
    private static final String DEV_INSTANCE = "DEV";

     private static HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifierForInstance(String instance, String hostnameVerification) {
        LOGGER.info("HostnameVerifier For Instance = {}, hostnameVerification = {}",instance,hostnameVerification);
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(instance)) {
            if ((instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(PROD_INSTANCE.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(STG_INSTANCE1.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(STG_INSTANCE2.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(QA_INSTANCE.toLowerCase()) || instance.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(DEV_INSTANCE.toLowerCase())) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(hostnameVerification) && hostnameVerification.trim().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        DefaultHostnameVerifier verifier = new DefaultHostnameVerifier();
                        return verifier.verify(hostname, session);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        return hostnameVerifier;
    }
}
```

Can this method be refactored/improved to a better version?

Comment: Everything in this class is private? How do you use it then?

Comment: If this is just an excerpt, then what else is in the `SSLConfig` class?

Comment: `toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("true")` use either or.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use `toLowerCase()` why wouldn't you define all your constants as lowercase to begin with, so that you don't need to call `toLowerCase()` on the constants for every comparison.

It also looks like you want to use an always-true verifier for your internal environments, and the default for all others.  Wouldn't it be safer to reverse your logic (make the `DefaultHostnameVerifier` your default, and change it if it's one of your environments), so that if there's a flaw in your logic, you don't return an always-true verifier by accident.

Generally, in this kind of scenario, returning the safer alternative by default and only returning a less-safe option when specific conditions pass is going to stand up better